# I sent a HTTP request. There is an error in View Results Tree. What wrong am I doing?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing, web-testing

I tried many different url but always getting same error. I am new in Jmeter and testing. Java is istalled in am computer.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pls show the error details. View Results Tree > Response data tab

Answer (score 0):

Your test looks good, just click on the `Facebook Home Page` in the Listener to see the summary. My expectation is that connection cannot be established i.e. you're sitting [behind a corporate firewall](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

In general,the fastest and the easiest way of getting a JMeter test script "skeleton" is **recording** using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). Check out [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide for instructions.

---

You can also consider using an alternative solution for recording a JMeter test, it has so called "SmartJMX" mode - automatic correlation of all dynamic parameters. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for details

Answer (score 0):

Check following:

1. If you are seeing socket connection error thne, If you are behind proxy, launch JMeter with -H server -P Port option (so that JMeter redirects the request.)
2. Change implementation to Java from httpclient4.

Answer (score 0):

**Now it is working perfect. I could not find why it was not running properly earlier. I did not made any changes.**

[image]